# Display image next to a text inside a Cytoscape Node

Tags: javascript, angular, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I've been struggling to display a small image and a text inside a node of a cytoscape graph.

I would like the node to look like this:

[image]

I just couldn't find any solution to do it.

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of what you already tried? Any context would be helpful, I personally can't see how I can help you without more details

Answer (score 0):

Should work. This is supported by the built-in feature of background images.
https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/background-image